# Magento 2 create new Store email Address

Tags: magento2

I want to create a new store email like **Custom Email 3**. As there are two emails already Magento has **Custom 1** and **Custom 2**. I want to add new **Custom 3**. I have tried to find any solution but failed. Any solution / Suggestion will be helpful. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create system.xml in your custom module with the following snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../Magento/Config/etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="trans_email">
            <tab>general</tab>
            <group id="ident_custom3" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="5" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Custom Email 3</label>
                <field id="email" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="2" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" canRestore="1">
                    <label>Sender Email</label>
                    <validate>validate-email</validate>
                    <backend_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Email\Address</backend_model>
                </field>
                <field id="name" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" canRestore="1">
                    <label>Sender Name</label>
                    <backend_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Email\Sender</backend_model>
                    <validate>validate-emailSender</validate>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```